# How to fix this console log error in installing the 2.0 version of magento?

Tags: magento2

I have a problem of installing magento 2.0.

How to fix this console log error in order for me to install the magento?

> [ERROR] exception 'Zend_Db_Exception' with message 'Column "code" does not exist in table "widget".' in C:\wamp\www\magent\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php:967 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\magent\vendor\magento\module-widget\Setup\InstallSchema.php(102): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->changeColumn('widget', 'code', 'widget_code', Array) #1 C:\wamp\www\magent\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(798): Magento\Widget\Setup\InstallSchema->install(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext)) #2 C:\wamp\www\magent\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(732): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), 'schema') #3 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema() #4 C:\wamp\www\magent\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(331): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5 C:\wamp\www\magent\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(97): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #6 C:\wamp\www\magent\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #7 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #8 C:\wamp\www\magent\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #9 C:\wamp\www\magent\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #10 C:\wamp\www\magent\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #11 C:\wamp\www\magent\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #12 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #13 C:\wamp\www\magent\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #14 C:\wamp\www\magent\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #15 C:\wamp\www\magent\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #16 C:\wamp\www\magent\setup\index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #17 {main}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you've dropped and re created the entire Magento database and install again. One way to do this is to install via CLI with the optional `--cleanup-database` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have entered right database name at database details step.
2. Check your database it must be clean.
3. Drop your database and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should never install Magento 2.0.

That realese was not stable.

Although, you will never be able to upgrade easily to Magento 2.1+.